# Why the option 'Not able to ask or answer questions' to explain why we delete our account?

Tags: feature-request

Clearly, nobody should say that he is "Not able to ask or answer questions". What is meant is something else, hopefully. I am personally disappointed that I have to close my SO account. SO was really and remains a successful idea and it will  still be useful to me to get answers. It is just that it's not given to every one to be able to contribute with questions and answers *as expected in SO.* It does not mean that my questions are not useful, but apparently they are not useful in a SO context.  So, in an approach of self-regulation, I am closing my account so that I am not tempted to ask my kind of questions *in SO.*  My point  is that it will be nicer if those who design the form to close an account would be more respectful of people that are disappointed to close their account, because they feel that they have good questions and could perhaps provide interesting answers to similar questions, but have not found that SO is the right place for these.

Comment: I only see one question that is upvoted. Do you have a bunch of deleted questions?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you are talking about?

Comment: @Tiny I have only one deleted question with one down vote. However, even before the down vote, I could see that it did not fit in SO.  So works great because it expects how-to questions with answers that you can implement and  easy check and that are related to a code issue that many people will also have.

Comment: What do you mean an example? There is only one form to request to delete an account. In this form, there is the option "Not able to ask or answer questions" to explain why. I feel that it makes no sense to even suggest that someone is not able to ask questions.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your deleted question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593152/why-a-single-socket-in-languages-such-as-python-cannot-be-used-to-request-many-c/42593683#42593683

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, you're actually talking about the form itself. People get question and answer bans, then they want to delete their accounts. The problem with that is the system keeps history on question and answer bans in mysterious ways, so that doesn't really work. I'm sure that option is there so that someone can inform the user of this fact. The whole account deletion process is manual as far as I know.

Comment: @Tiny, I don't understand your explanation. I don't see the connection with the fact that some people get banned. So, I am not sure you understand my point. The form is for someone like me to complete. I do not address myself to "a user" when I complete that form. Are you saying that you are on purpose suggesting that some people are "not able to ask or answer questions", in general, and that you on purpose want them to admit that on the form?

Comment: If the reason they want to delete their account is that they have been blocked from asking or answer questions (hence not able to ask or answer questions), that is important information for the person who is going to be conducting the account deletion process on the Stack Overflow end.

Comment: Yes, with the help of the answer below, now I understand the purpose. It's fine. However, for someone like me that complete the form, this purpose is not clear. "Not able" does not mean that "Not allowed" or "Banned from". Unless, it is that I do not understand English at all.

Comment: Not able means to not have the ability to do something. That inability can be caused by any number of reasons. The form does not suggest that users who are not able to ask or answer questions for whatever reason should delete their accounts. There are plenty of actions on the site that you can perform other than ask or answer. It is for mediation purposes because stack overflow doesn't want you to delete your account.

Comment: I think what I meant was pretty clear. You had the viewpoint of someone that sees the situation from a different perspective, completely innocent regarding banning considerations, not thinking about that. You do whatever you want with this. I am done.

Answer (score 2):

That option is there because there are quite a few users that *can't* ask questions, and a fair number that can't *answer* questions. By "can't", I don't mean just that they can't do it *right*, but the site is [actively (and automatically) blocking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) them from writing **any** posts of that type **indefinitely**, because their history is so bad.

(For what it's worth, deleting an account that's q-blocked or a-blocked, then creating another account to try again, won't generally lift these restrictions, and the site will automatically detect those attempts.)

You don't appear to have gotten to this point, or even necessarily to the point of getting automatic warnings that you're approaching it, so there's not much to worry about, and the contact form is not trying to insult you, or addressing you at all with that particular option.

Comment: I got it. Then I would suggest a rephrasing or may be I didn't read carefully.  If it said "I am not allowed to ask or answer questions" or, better,  "I was banned from asking or answering questions", then there would have been no confusion. Clearly "Not able to ask or answer questions" mean something else.

Comment: @Dominic108: "Unable"/"not able" can mean either inherent lack of the necessary qualities, or some external factor that prevents it. In this case, it's really some of both.

Comment: It seems confusing to mix these two meanings and I don't think the other meaning should be offered as an option in this form. If you want to allow the other meaning, do it explicitly in a way that is more appropriate. Usually, it's more that the questions do not fit in SO. As they say, there is no bad questions. Only bad answers or bad people to ask.

Comment: @Dominic108: On SO, there are a *lot* of bad questions. Most of them are pretty lazy and pretty selfish, so it's not hard to label them "bad" accordingly.

Comment: Oh well, if you really believe that the form should be confusing and not allow someone to be very clear on what he means by a simple click on an option, then we are done.

Comment: @Dominic108 You're pointing out a possible problem without offering a solution.  It's confusing to you.  Okay, what do you want us to do about it?  Do you have a better way of communicating what that sentence is attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Sure. Offer the option "Banned from asking or answering questions" instead of "Unable to ask or answer questions".  Otherwise, people like me that are aware that their questions do not fit will get confused. It will be also better for you. You will know exactly what the guy means.

Comment: @Dominic108: You need to use the @ username syntax to notify Daedalus of your reply.

Comment: @Daedalus I replied.

Comment: @Dominic108 But that doesn't cover the numerous other reasons why someone would not be able to ask or answer.  That specific sentence, the one that is there currently, is meant to be vague, as I understand it, for that very reason.

Comment: @Daedalus Oh well !  You really believe yourself when you justify being vague and, I emphasize that, thus confusing.  I am not even going to try suggest an alternative approach. Let me instead appreciate Stack Overflow for what it is. A strong system full of dynamic people, moving fast toward its goal, thus naturally a bit out of control and pushing away anyone that does not fit in that goal. So, thank you for what you offer to the world. I don't see that I am part of that bolide, a specific group phenomena,  and it's ok.

Comment: Regarding the "Put on hold" as unclear, I think, on the contrary, what I wrote was clear.  Of course, it's part of communication that we need to explain further. It does mean that there was a problem with the initial question.  This tag shows that, as a group, you lost the way to communicate. This is exactly what I mean by you are a bit out of control, pushing away anyone that does not immediately fit with your goal.

Comment: @Dominic108 I can see you're unwilling to discuss this in a constructive manner, so I'm bowing out now.

Comment: It's not that I don't appreciate that what SO is doing is very useful and successful. It's just that when a group is so successful it tends to act as if the world ends with them. For example, you have used the same approach for communication in the Meta as within SO itself. This is because you feel the SO approach is universal to manage an answer/ question setting. It's not the case at all. In general, you don't expect questions to be "clear" at first. It's part of communication that it gets clarified.  In SO, it can be clear at first, because it's a specific context.

Comment: @Daedalus, I know that the TAG asked for clarification, but it's not the way to proceed. Also,  downvotes are not useful communication tool here. It's a way to push people away.  I can believe that you cannot take a step back and see what is happening. I had this TAG and all these downvotes - so I thought, OK it does not work... What do you expect. You expect me to start to think that I AM WRONG because of this TAG and downvotes? I am not impress. This is just a system that is not working. I you want people to show an interest in communication, then have a better system.

Comment: @Dominic108: Nobody requires MSO questions to be clear *at first*, just *eventually*. That's why "on hold" is more of a temporary state if edited within 5 days.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It should be considered the normal case that the question needs clarification. So, have a special tag for when a question is clear at first and no tag for the normal case. I am joking for a tag when the question is clear at first, but not for no tag in the normal case.  This tag is innapropriate. The basic point is that applying the same approach in meta as in SO itself shows that you misunderstood that your success was due to a specific context.

Comment: @Dominic108: Surprisingly, most people are able to ask questions that are clear enough, even on meta; "unclear" is probably not even the most common close reason, and it's definitely not enormously more common than on SO.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Probably, but it's because you pushed away all the people that ask questions from an innocent outside perspective. So, yes, you are right, when people share a same context, it is often clear at first.

Comment: The success of SO is based on that. The shared context is the language constructs. It's a very specific context. Your success is based on the fact that you ask for questions that are based on this shared context, even with an issue that can be answered by a piece of code and thus verified objectively, no long discussion, etc.

Comment: @Dominic108: I'm also including the countless questions asked by new users all the time. MSO is far from having pushed away everyone that doesn't fit into its little niche. 12% of the last 50 questions were asked by users with less than 100 rep (one of which was closed, as a duplicate), and a further 8% were asked by users with less than 1000 rep. (Also, the idea that the SE model cannot cope with anything outside coding questions is belied by the 160+ other sites in the network.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Well, do your analysis. I am pretty sure that the other sites that are the most successful also have a strong shared context to build on. The other point is that the fact that you leveraged the success of SO to attract other sites does not mean that your approach is ideal for these other sites.

Comment: @NathanTuggy. I never said that you push away the new users.  I said that you push away those who do not fit in the framework and, in the case of SO, it's fine that you do.  Of course, you do, not the SO managers, but the system. It's very easy to spot a question that does not fit and it gets quickly downvoted. Now, a question that does not fit might still be interesting, but it's fine to downvote it anyway.